# Start ListPreference (fragment) from MenuItem

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, menuitem

I'm trying to start up a preference fragment from a MenuItem and I'm having some trouble. I followed a tutorial on how to make a listPreference and then adapted it to my project, but it crashes the app.

This is the item in which is the launch point for the intenet to the prefFrag:

```
<item
                android:id="@+id/action_settings"
                android:orderInCategory="100"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="@string/settings"
                android:onClick="prefStartup"/>
```

Here is the code that launches the intent in the main activity:

```
public void prefStartup(MenuItem item){
    Intent intentSetPref = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PrefActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intentSetPref, 0);
}
```

Here are the two classes that help display the fragment (straight from the tutorial):

```
public class PrefActivity extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  PrefFragment prefFragment = new PrefFragment();
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
  fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, prefFragment);
  fragmentTransaction.commit();
 } 

}
```

```
public class PrefFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);
 } 
}
```

I'm not really sure why it would be breaking if the stuff is straight from the tutorial. In the tutorial though they just launch it from a regular button rather than a MenuItem.

Comment: If you have found the answer to this question, please add it as an answer. [Answering you own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) is highly encouraged!

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same tutorial as you not long ago and managed to stumble my way through the same problem.

Instead of using your prefStartup() try the following in your main activity.

```
   //Method for creating options menu
   @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }

   //Method for handling options menu selection
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // action with ID action_settings was selected
    case R.id.action_settings:
   Intent intentSetPref = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PrefActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(intentSetPref, 0);
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }

    return true;
  }
```

You can remove the android:onClick="prefStartup" from your menu xml as well.